# Output parameter value changes depending on error type

Tags: sql-server

I have a Stored procedure with an output parameter. In my procedure I have two lines with error and depending on which error is raised the value of the output parameter is different. Help me understand such kind of behavior of the output parameter.

Here is the example:

```
CREATE PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN
 SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;
 select 5/0 
END
go



DECLARE @v int;
SET @v = 1;
EXEC SP @v OUTPUT;
PRINT @v;
go
--------------------------------
```

result is 11

```
CREATE PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN
 SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;
 SELECT * FROM nonExistentTable; 
END
go


DECLARE @v int;
SET @v = 1;
EXEC SP @v OUTPUT;
PRINT @v;
go
--------------------------------
```

result is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been through several iterations of this answer, as I have found out more. I think I have now come to a conclusion.

As OP has pointed out, the non-return of the updated parameter is because of the copy-in/copy-out operation of the OUTPUT parameters. However, I have found that a non-existent table error appears not to be picked up by TRY-CATCH inside the SP, but is caught by TRY-CATCH outside.

The following is an amended version of the second example, using `TRY..CATCH` to pinpoint where the error is picked up.

I used this code to run all variants of the SP:

```
DECLARE @v int, @result int = 0, @Flag int = 1;
SET @v = 1;
BEGIN TRY
    SET @Flag = 2;
    EXEC @Result = SP @v OUTPUT;
    SET @Flag = 3;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ' C:   @Flag=' + CAST( @Flag AS Varchar(10) );

    SET @Flag = 4;

END CATCH

PRINT  ' D:      @v=' + CAST( @v AS Varchar(10) );
PRINT  ' E: @Result=' + CAST( @Result AS Varchar(10) );
PRINT  ' F:   @Flag=' + CAST( @Flag AS Varchar(10) );
```

The first version of the SP is:

```
ALTER PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN

    PRINT '>> SP';

    SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;

    PRINT '  A: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

             SELECT * FROM nonExistentTable; 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @p1 = 999;
            RETURN 22;
        END CATCH;  

        RETURN 399;

    END

    PRINT '  B: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    PRINT '<< SP';

END
```

The output is:

```
>> SP
  A: @p1=11
  C:   @Flag=2
  D:      @v=1
  E: @Result=0
  F:   @Flag=4
```

So it appears that, even though the output parameter @p1 is updated within the SP, the value of the parameter is not passed back to the caller. The non-existent table error is not trapped by the TRY-CATCH *inside* the SP and by-passes any updates to OUTPUT parameters, but it is caught by the TRY-CATCH *outside* the SP.

Now, having tested that, I added some additional code into the SP:

```
ALTER PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN

    PRINT '>> SP';

    SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;

    PRINT '  A: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'nonExistentTable'))

    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

             SELECT * FROM nonExistentTable; 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @p1 = 999;
            RETURN 22;
        END CATCH;  

        RETURN 399;

    END

    PRINT '  B: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    PRINT '<< SP';

END
```

with this result:

```
>> SP
  A: @p1=11
  B: @p1=11
<< SP
 D:      @v=11
 E: @Result=0
 F:   @Flag=3
```

which is intriguing. So I changed the SP again, this time to select rows from a table that I know contains data:

```
ALTER PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN

    PRINT '>> SP';

    SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;

    PRINT '  A: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Data_Table )
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

             SELECT * FROM nonExistentTable; 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @p1 = 999;
            RETURN 22;
        END CATCH;  

        RETURN 399;

    END

    PRINT '  B: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    PRINT '<< SP';

END
```

In this case the result is:

```
>> SP
  A: @p1=11
 C:   @Flag=2
 D:      @v=1
 E: @Result=0
 F:   @Flag=4
```

Finally a check on a completely unrelated table that is empty:

```
ALTER PROC SP (@p1 int OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN

    PRINT '>> SP';

    SET @p1 = @p1 + 10;

    PRINT '  A: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Empty_Table )
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

             SELECT * FROM nonExistentTable; 
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @p1 = 999;
            RETURN 22;
        END CATCH;  

        RETURN 399;

    END

    PRINT '  B: @p1=' + CAST( @P1 as varchar(10) );

    PRINT '<< SP';

END
```

with the result:

```
>> SP
  A: @p1=11
  B: @p1=11
<< SP
 D:      @v=11
 E: @Result=0
 F:   @Flag=3
```

Someone who knows more about how the internals of SQL Server work might be able to explain and, perhaps, justify these results.

Comment: In case of `IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Data_Table )` the value of `@p1` is 1 because of `copy-in/copy-out semantic` of the output parameter.
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/06/09/tsql-basics-ii-parameter-passing-semantics/

Comment: Thanks @KarenAvdalyan that makes sense. But I still wonder why the non-existent table error is not trapped by the TRY-CATCH inside the SP, when it is reliably trapped outside the SP.

Comment: I think here is the answer of your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015051/sql-try-catch-doesnt-catch-an-error-when-attempting-to-access-a-table-that-it

Comment: I tested this again by having another stored proc that calls the one in which the error occurs, within a TRY-CATCH, and as explained in the article you pointed to, the error is caught in the calling SP. I guess the conclusion is, if there is any possibility of a non-existent object, then always check for its existence before referring to it within the SP.