# Nested Try/Catches - Does Only Outer Catch Matter (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, exception, try-catch

I thought that nested TRY/CATCH were supported. However, it seems that when nested try/catch are used, the outer most CATCH is the one doing the catching.

In the example below, what prints is:

TRY 1
TRY 2
CATCH 1

Shouldn't CATCH 2 be printed? I would expect that CATCH 2 is run and CATCH 1 is never hit.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST__Main AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY 
    PRINT 'TRY 1'
    EXEC TEST__Main_1;
    PRINT 'END 1'
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'CATCH 1'
  END CATCH 
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST__Main_1 AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY 
    PRINT 'TRY 2'
        SELECT * FROM table_doesnt_exist;
    PRINT 'END 2'
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'CATCH 2'
  END CATCH 
END
GO

EXEC TEST__Main;
```

Comment: Change your `SELECT * FROM shjhjsjhsjhsjhsjhsjhsjhsjh;` to `SELECT 1/0` and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate [SQL: Try/Catch doesn't catch an error when attempting to access a table that it can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15015051/1048425)

Comment: @JacobH that works as expected, but not the missing table - which is answered by GarethD comment - obviously I don't search as well as he does :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in @GarethD's comment. Adding here as the answer so that it can be found by the next victim. I didn't come across that question while searching.

[SQL: Try/Catch doesn't catch an error when attempting to access a table that it can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015051/sql-try-catch-doesnt-catch-an-error-when-attempting-to-access-a-table-that-it)

GarethD, if you post an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.