# An inconsistent problem of Try-Catch in SQL command, executed in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, error-handling, try-catch

I use Try-Catch to skip some error-prone SQL command in C# but I **sometimes** still get an execution/runtime error.

My C# code to work with a SQL server database will run frequently. On the first run, there's somewhere in my code that I try to update a table which doesn't exist yet (Later on in the code the table in discussion will be created). I put the part of query in a try-catch, but **sometimes** still get the error that `Invalid object name 'destination_table'`.
My code is like this:

```
string query_str =
                " BEGIN TRY " +
                " UPDATE [my_DB].[dbo].[destination_table] " +
                " SET the_column = 'the_value' " +
                " END TRY " +
                " BEGIN CATCH " +
                " END CATCH ";
using (SqlCommand my_command = new SqlCommand(query_str , conn))                
 { form_rack_command.ExecuteNonQuery();  }
```

The solutions in this link seem good [SQL: Try/Catch doesn't catch an error when attempting to access a table that it can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015051/sql-try-catch-doesnt-catch-an-error-when-attempting-to-access-a-table-that-it)
But my problem is that I can't always reproduce the error. It seems like sometimes when I start my computer and open Microsoft Visual Studio, I get the error on the first run of the program. But not even shutting down the system and restart everything can always cause the error.
What can be the reason that sometimes I have this problem and sometimes not?

Comment: SQL Try/Catch doesn't help because that's a *compilation* error. You may not always think of it but when you submit a script to the server, it's first compiled and *then* executed. Try/Catch don't help if none of the code is ever *executed* because of a compile error.

Comment: *"I use Try-Catch to skip some error-prone SQL command in C# but I sometimes still get the error."* Because `TRY` doesn't stop all errors, and just throwing the error away is a (for lack of better word) foolish idea; fix the problem don't ignore it... It's like writing a VB application and implementing `On Error Resume Next`; it's never a good idea. The *real* problem here is you are ignoring all the errors your application is `THROW`ing at you, and you should really be looking at them and addressing the, so that the errors don't occur any more.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for your answer. So, you say that SQL try-catch won't work when I use it in C#? Then why sometimes it works and catches the error?

Comment: *"So, you say that SQL try-catch won't work when I use it in C#?"* That isn't what @Damien_The_Unbeliever says at all, Iraj. They explicitly say that `TRY...CATCH` won't "catch" compile errors. Nor does it "catch" syntax errors.

Comment: @Larnu I edited that part of my post. When I say "I still get  error" I mean runtime error, execution failure and not catching the error by try-catch. 
I wrote the code intentionally like that because the absence of the aforementioned table happens only once (first time) while the code will be run forever (frequently)

Comment: @Larnu The try-catch in my SQL command DOES work but not all the time. In different identical execution of C# code, only sometimes when I log in to my system it doesn't work.

Comment: @Iraj if you have a `TRY...CATCH` and nothing in the `CATCH` the `TRY` is *completely* pointless in my view. If you are implementing a `TRY...CATCH` do *something* with the error; you might not `THROW` it, but certainly at least log it, or choose each errors to ignore and `THROW` the rest. The fact that you are ignoring the errors is why you are having even more problems. You've gone down a rabbit hole you never should have done.

Comment: @Larnu As I said, I use this try-catch to skip an error on the first time run of the code (out of many thousands times) and I don't need that error message especially because it will be in SQL and I'm working in C#. Also there is no problem with leaving catch statement empty. I have tested it. My problem is not that though...

Comment: You could execute  the `UPDATE` statement with `sp_executesql` (and I strongly recommend you parameterize it) so that it can be caught in the outer scope catch block. That will catch compilation errors in the inner scope.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you. I will read about how to use sp_execuresql. But my current problem is that I can't reproduce the error all the time, and until I can do that, no solution can be trustable. I first need to know "why" only sometimes I have this problem.

Comment: *"As I said, I use this try-catch to skip an error on the first time run of the code (out of many thousands times)"* Then why not add the error number in an `IF` in the `CATCH` and the `THROW` any others... `IF NOT(@@ERROR_NUMBER = {Your Error Number you don't care about}) THROW;` at least you then still error on other things instead of hiding them.